# Questions regarding IndexSearcher/IndexReader and Directory

Tags: java, lucene

I am making some changes to an existing code base where Lucene version 3.6.1 is used.

The IndexSearcher has been instantiated with every search request.

```
 IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index);
 IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
```

A `RAMDirectory` has been used and the [close](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html#close%28%29) method has not been caleed.

Periodic re-indexing is done and new instance of RAMDirectory is created when this happens. But the existing IndexReader#close method has not been called.

The following are my questions.

1. What is the impact of not calling close method on the IndexReader?
2. What is the impact of not calling close method on the RAMDirectory?
3. A reference to the index reader is not kept anywhere. So in order to close it, can I do IndexSearcher.ggetIndexReader().close()?
4. Is there a similar way to get access to the Directory so that I can close it when the re-indexing happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q> What is the impact of not calling close method on the IndexReader?
A> For filesystem-based indices you would likely run of file descriptors. But if all `IndexSearcher`s and `IndexReader`s become GCable, this shouldn't be a big deal. That is, if you don't care of occasional memory spikes -- but that depends on your usage patterns.

Q> What is the impact of not calling close method on the RAMDirectory?
A> Internal map wouldn't get cleared. Again, if you throw away instance of `RAMDirectory` and recreate it, not a big deal. But I'd still close it to avoid stealthy bugs and possibly help GC.

Q> A reference to the index reader is not kept anywhere. So in order to close it, can I do `IndexSearcher.getIndexReader().close()?` 
A> Yes, once `IndexSearcher` is created, it always keeps reference to the original `IndexReader` which can be accessed using above mentioned method.

Q> Is there a similar way to get access to the Directory so that I can close it when the re-indexing happens?
A> No. You are meant to preserve this reference.